# derivative of a derivative with respect to another variable

Tags: derivatives, physics, differential

This problem comes from my physics lectures so hope i am not wrong here because its still a Mathmatical Problem.

So i have to derive a function $W(q(t),\dot q,t)$ that is defined for example as $W =a\dot q^2$

Now i have to differentiate it with respects to q partialy so $\frac{\partial (a\dot q^2)}{\partial q} $

How do i solve this, also does someone know good reading matter on those kinds of abstract differentials(hope thats the right word)
Thank you very much

Comment: Is it calculus of variations? If yes, then It's $0$ because we are treating $W$ as a function of $q$, $\dot{q}$ and $t$.

Comment: To emphasize, $q$ and $\dot q$ are treated as independent variables.

Comment: Its part of Analytical Mechanics, we arr going in the direction of Lagrange Equations. If that helps